# image path saving in database but image is not in destination folder

Tags: php

Hello i'm having this issue here that i have a task here i need to upload images in the folder and save the path of the images in database. Now i have this code that path is getting save in database and if i try to upload the same file which i uploaded before it gives me the message of file exists already but in the destination folder no image is showing. kindly help me here. Here is my code

directory-image.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>image in directory</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="directory-imagedatabase.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label>Choose File to Upload:</label><br />

<input type="hidden" name="id" />

<input type="file" name="uploadimage" /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" id="upload" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

directory-imagedatabase.php

```
<?php
$target_Folder = '/officework/php-startup/images/';

$uid = $_POST['id'];

$target_Path = $target_Folder.basename( $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'] );

$savepath = $target_Path.basename( $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'] );

    $file_name = $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'];

    if(file_exists('/officework/php-startup/images/'.$file_name))
{
    echo "That File Already Exisit";
    }
    else
    {

        // Database 
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","sal123","test"); //Change it if required

//Check Connection
        if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to database" .     mysqli_connect_errno();
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO directoryimage (id,image, image_name)
                    VALUES     ('','$target_Folder$file_name','$file_name') ";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
        echo "1 record added successfully in the database";
        echo '<br />';
        mysqli_close($con);

        // Move the file into UPLOAD folder

        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name'],     $target_Path );

        echo "File Uploaded <br />";
        echo 'File Successfully Uploaded to:&nbsp;' . $target_Path;
        echo '<br />';  
        echo 'File Name:&nbsp;' . $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'];
        echo'<br />';
        echo 'File Type:&nbsp;' . $_FILES['uploadimage']['type'];
        echo'<br />';
        echo 'File Size:&nbsp;' . $_FILES['uploadimage']['size'];

    }
?>
<a href="show-directory.php">Show Image</a>
```

Comment: i did not find any issue in your code, working fine

Comment: first when you upload new file check it upload in your folder?

Comment: check your folder already exit and path info ok if not work then change it

$target_Folder = '/officework/php-startup/images/';
to
$target_Folder = 'officework/php-startup/images/';

Comment: no its not uploading in my folder

Comment: then upload problem. ok wait

Comment: yes folder exists!! and i have tried this way to my removing slash but still it didn't work

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam the image folder is in the same folder where i'm keeping my code. I guess there is some issue with path

Comment: ok i will give you full code

Comment: ok sir i'm waiting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145358/discussion-between-shafiqul-islam-and-dawood-basharat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your main file same folder then update

```
$target_Folder = '/officework/php-startup/images/';
```

to

```
$target_Folder = 'officework/php-startup/images/';
```

then this is your total code

```
<?php
$target_Folder = 'officework/php-startup/images/';

$uid = $_POST['id'];

$target_Path = $target_Folder.basename( $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'] );

$savepath = $target_Path.basename( $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'] );

    $file_name = $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'];

    if(file_exists('officework/php-startup/images/'.$file_name))
{
    echo "That File Already Exisit";
    }
    else
    {

        // Database
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","sal123","test"); //Change it if required

//Check Connection
        if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to database" .     mysqli_connect_errno();
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO directoryimage (id,image, image_name)
                    VALUES     ('','$target_Folder.$file_name','$file_name') ";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
        echo "1 record added successfully in the database";
        echo '<br />';
        mysqli_close($con);

        // Move the file into UPLOAD folder

        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name'],     $target_Path );

        echo "File Uploaded <br />";
        echo 'File Successfully Uploaded to:&nbsp;' . $target_Path;
        echo '<br />';
        echo 'File Name:&nbsp;' . $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'];
        echo'<br />';
        echo 'File Type:&nbsp;' . $_FILES['uploadimage']['type'];
        echo'<br />';
        echo 'File Size:&nbsp;' . $_FILES['uploadimage']['size'];

    }
?>
<a href="show-directory.php">Show Image</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO directoryimage (id,image, image_name)
                    VALUES     ('','$target_Folder$file_name','$file_name') ";
```

Change it to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO directoryimage (id,image, image_name)
                    VALUES     ('','".$target_Folder."/".$file_name."','".$file_name."') ";
```

Comment: If the answer is useful, press up arrow.